# How to set up rails and mysql on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed ruby on rails and mysql on windows with

http://railsinstaller.org/

```
C:\Sites>rails -v
Rails 3.2.12

C:\Sites>rails new simple_cms  -d mysql
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.0.3)
Using i18n (0.6.4)
Installing multi_json (1.7.0)
Using activesupport (3.2.12)
Using builder (3.0.4)
Using activemodel (3.2.12)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.5)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.5)
Using sprockets (2.2.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.12)
Using mime-types (1.21)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.12)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.12)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
Using activerecord (3.2.12)
Using activeresource (3.2.12)
Using bundler (1.3.3)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.1)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
Installing json (1.7.7)
Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
Using thor (0.17.0)
Using railties (3.2.12)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using jquery-rails (2.2.1)
Installing mysql2 (0.3.11)
Using rails (3.2.12)
Using sass (3.2.7)
Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
Installing uglifier (1.3.0)
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Post-install message from rdoc:
Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
Post-install message from mysql2:

================================================================================
======================

  You've installed the binary version of mysql2.
  It was built using MySQL Connector/C version 6.0.2.
  It's recommended to use the exact same version to avoid potential issues.

  At the time of building this gem, the necessary DLL files where available
  in the following download:

  http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0
.2-win32.zip/from/pick

  And put lib\libmysql.dll file in your Ruby bin directory, for example C:\Ruby\
bin

================================================================================
======================


C:\Sites>rails server
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
.exe
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a files
ystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a fil
esystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options:
mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3
/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                 # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                 # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing t
o your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing t
o Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on
 Ruby >= 1.9

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.

C:\Sites>cmd.exe
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I can run in a browser when I do
C:\Sites>rails new simple_cms
but get a 502 error with
C:\Sites>rails new simple_cms  -d mysql

I want to get ruby on rails and mysql working together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to set up your database connection in database.yml, you are also going to need to set permissions for a mysql user to allow it to create a database for you.

There are many guides to doing this if you google it.

If this is your first time on rails, there is is a really good tutorial that covers lots of the basic setup, from install through to a relatively sophisticated app.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: I am not using the database yet.  And the lynda.com ruby on rails tutorial worked for the instructor without specificity of database username, database password.  The 502 error I receive is on all pages when attempting to do the project before hello world (the project that requires no changes).